# ERROR: Trying to Tweet an image + text with Twitter API V1 and V2 endpoints

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to  create a bot to extract info from a source and tweet it as an image + text everyday.

I know that V1 endpoints will not work, but so far i read it still support media upload. The V2 endpoint tweets a text.

I have managed to tweet via V2 endpoint text but I cant manage to tweet the image..

Any help wowould be grateful. Thanks.

Here is my code.. I have errors (tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request Your media IDs are invalid.)

```
    def Tweet(self, date: str):
    
        consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        
        client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',consumer_key= consumer_key,consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)
        
      
        # Authenticate with Twitter
       
        auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
            consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
        )
       
        
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        
        image_path = "C:\wex\pic.jpg" 
        
        with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
            r1 = api.media_upload(filename='pic.jpg', file=image_file)

        media_id = r1.media_id_string    

        media = api.media_upload(filename=image_path)
        
        client.create_tweet(text="This Tweet IS A TEST SORRY!", media_ids=[media_id])
 
        log.info("Posted!")
```

I have tried many lines of code but was unsuccessful... thers always an error.. tried the help of ChatGPT but still have errors...

Comment: Is this a typo - `media_id = r1.media_id_strin  ` - should it say `media_id = r1.media_id_string`?

Comment: I was a typo here in stackoverflow... the code mentions "media_id = r1.media_id_string" correctly. thanks!

Comment: No worries. I guess you've used a print statement to check the returned value for `media_id` is valid first? Before you pass it into the client.create_tweet method?

Comment: Yes and it think it was all ok... here is what i got..

Comment: Media(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x000001C109379648>, media_id=1686071444873101316, media_id_string='1686071444873101316', size=3342190, expires_after_secs=86400, image={'image_type': 'image/jpeg', 'w': 3050, 'h': 10795})
1686071444873101316
['1686071444873101316']

Comment: Ok it looks like it’s returning an object with multiple properties (media_id, media_id_string, size, expires_after_secs etc). You need to extract the value from ‘media_id’.

Comment: Perhaps this is because the file is more than 3Mb... I think there is an upload limit on Twitter... . I tried to post a file below 3Mb and was posted...

Answer (score 0):

This work with me as of today:

```
#access_token
ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
#access_token_secret
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXX'
#consumer_key
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'
#consumer_secret
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXX'




api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
access_token=ACCESS_KEY,
access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)


auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET
)
oldapi = tweepy.API(auth)
media1 = oldapi.media_upload(temp + "output.jpg")
#media2 = oldapi.media_upload("img2.jpg")

#api.create_tweet(text='I want to Post 3 Photos and description',media_ids=[media1.media_id, media2.media_id, media3.media_id])
response = api.create_tweet(text=message,media_ids=[media1.media_id],alt_text="ddd")

print(response)
```